# Непонятные полосы после рендера

Tags: 3d, model, blender, render

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? После рендера местами появляются черные полосы.

[image: bl]

Comment: Может тут есть ответ https://amp.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/61atka/how_do_i_fix_these_extra_black_lines/

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем была проблема. Случайно включил FreeStyle в настройках рендера.